# How to add more files to be copied by Sync task, but only for one project

Tags: gradle

I have a multi project build with one root project and many sub-projects.

In the root configuration I have many task in common for all sub-projects.
I would like to extend one of them, only for a specific subproject

```
task distrib_bin(type: Sync) {
        into "$buildDir/custom-distrib"
        from '../bin-dist'
 }
```

For that project (for example project 'broker') I need to add some files to the previous Sync task.
I tried with project.ext properties but I think I'm very far from the solution.
Thanks for all your help

Comment: So you declare this task in the root build script inside `subprojects { ... }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your subproject build file simply say:

```
distrib_bin {
    from ... //whatever files you need to add here
}
```

It will allow you add more configuration to the task.

Comment: Oh, my. You are so right! thank you. Sorry for the basic question!